# Get small keyboard on iOS8?

Tags: iphone, ios8, uikeyboard

So, I got the following image from graphic designer.

[image: Different keyboards]

On the right is keyboard popping in our application, on the left is keyboard he sees everywhere else on his phone (iPhone 6), apparently. He wants the keyboard on the left to appear in our application too. This looks like standard iOS keyboard, only smaller, but I don't see any option to get it. How do I get it? Or is it just particularly popular custom keyboard/extension? Or maybe it's really easy to do custom keyboard/extension (note, I don't know a thing about custom keyboards/extensions in iOS)?

Comment: They are the same size. The one on the left seems shorter because it includes the suggestion bar, but you can't just hide it and keep the rest of the "short" keyboard. The suggestion bar is a part of the whole keyboard.

Comment: @Cyrille except that if I enable suggestion bar, keyboard in my app is still the same size. If you look closer on the picture you'll notice that "small" keyboard with suggestion bar is actually higher than "normal" keyboard without one.

Comment: Obviously, the keyboard on the left is a screenshot from iOS 8. The one on the right leads me to think it's iOS 7.0 (the Shift key was turned white in iOS 7.1). This is the kind of slight differences you encounter across different versions of iOS that you must take into account, and that you are not in control of.

Comment: @Cyrille while I can't really say if my graphic designer did the right screenshot on iOS7, I can attest that keyboard size is the same for suggestion bar enabled/disabled on iOS8 in my app on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard is adjusted when you have `inputAccessoryView` assigned for active field.

check: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

Comment: It doesn't resize keyboard when I set inputAccessoryView. It's just presented above keyboard but keyboard height in itself is still the same as before.